# System.Windows.Forms in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I noticed a reference exists for System.Windows.Forms in Excel's VBE, Tools, References.

Is it possible to show a Windows Form within the VBE? I know I can create a Windows Form during runtime in PowerShell, but so far my attempts to create/show a Windows form using VBA have failed. For example,

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oForm As New System_Windows_Forms.Form
    
    oForm.Show

End Sub
```

If I'm trying something impossible, what is the reference used for? Individual controls?

Also, if System_Windows_Forms is a no-go, any other methods to show a non-VBA userform within the VBE? The "old" method of showing a regular userform and just hiding the Excel Application is not really what I'm after.

Comment: If you follow the steps to recreate the TLB file using `regasm /codebase system.windows.forms.dll` in the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and use it as shown in the link above then it will work. (Tested it myself). BTW remember if you are planning to distribute the Excel file to other users then this option is a **bad idea**!

Comment: Hi Siddharth. Sounds dodgy then.  What is the actual purpose of the reference? To make windows forms available in VBA?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: The duplicate shows how to create a reference to System.Windows.Forms and use it to solve a specific problem (rich text conversion). That's not what the OP asked, hence my vote to reopen.

Comment: Did Siddharth close it? I wouldn't have used CAPS if I thought it was him :)

Comment: @Andrew he did, probably because the link shows how to make the system forms available in VBA. Did you try it? Or where are you still stuck?

Comment: Hi PEH, I want to create a windows form and add controls. I didn't see how this is possible with the code in the linked question. Perhaps the image was a clue. It's blocked where I work in any case. If I can actually create a form and add some controls, that would be great, just need to know how to get started and go from there.

Comment: Also, why would distributing the file be a bad idea? Something to do with .NET versions?

Comment: **1.** I closed it as a duplicate because the question may have been about `.RichTextBox` but it uses `System_Windows_Forms` and to use `System_Windows_Forms.Form` or `System_Windows_Forms.RichTextBox` you will have to follow the same steps as mentioned in the answer by Robert. **2.** It is a bad idea because the destination pc may not have the relevant dll/tlb

Comment: I can re-open it and post a solution but it would be an exact duplicate of the solution given by Robert. Like I mentioned in the 1st comment. I tested it and it works. Try this **1.** Close Excel. **2.** Open command prompt as an administrator. **3.** Go to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` **4.** Run `regasm /codebase system.windows.forms.dll` **5.** Open releavant Excel file and go to VBE to set the reference. **6.** Browse to folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and select `system.windows.forms.tlb`. Thats it. Now your code will work.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. Unfortunately I can't log in as an admin so I can't try it out :( Is there some other way to do the set up? Also, any possibility the dll and tlb could be sent/registered with addin? Sorry, if it's a stupid question, but I don't know about them, only I've seen but never tried code to register DLLs and set a reference using VBA.